# using guice trancactional attribute for hibernate without JPA

Tags: hibernate, guice

my use of hibernate looks like the following:

this is how I configure the sessionFactory

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                                            .addResource(MAPPING_RESSOURCE)// -> hibernate.hbm.xml
                                            .configure(CONFIG_RESSOURCE)// -> hibernate.cfg.xml;

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                                            .buildServiceRegistry();

    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

SessionFactory is configured to use ThreadLocalSessionContext ( line from hibernate.cfg.xml ):

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

I acquire the current session from this dao base method:

```
protected Session getSession(){return factory.getCurrentSession();}
```

and I got some methods for CRUD operations in an abstract dao baseclass, like this one for 'get':

```
public T get(int key) throws HibernateException
{       
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        Session session = getSession();

        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        T t = (T)session.get(classOfT, key);

        transaction.commit();

        return t;
    }
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {
        if(transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();

        throw e;
    }       
}
```

now here's the question. I would like to use guice's transactional attribute to shorten the code like this:

```
@Transactional
public T get(int key) throws HibernateException
{       
    T t = (T)session.get(classOfT, key);                
}
```

however, all the tutorials I've seen indicate that guice persistence support is tailored for JPA, that is EntityManager, persistence.xml and so forth. Is there a possibility to keep my above shown setup and use @Transactional?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Warp-persist](http://www.wideplay.com/guicewebextensions2). I've been using it even after guice-persist came out. So far had 0 issues after years of usage. Used mostly session-per-transaction strategy.

http://www.wideplay.com/webextensions%3A%3Ajpaintegration2

The only catch is you have to build it from sources and deploy it to company nexus. It is painless but takes a few moments to do.

http://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/source/checkout

Alternatively if you want to use Guice-persist then just supply the persistence.xml something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"></property> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and make your own providers for Native Hibernate API (they get injected the JPA API and you just return the underlying implementation - Hibernate). E.g. in a module do

```
@Provides Session emToSession(EntityManager em){ 
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

Comment: this answer sounds profound, thank you. warp-persist seems to be what I was looking for. however, it is somewhat odd that they dont provide a maven repo and that the last commit was several years ago. but at least there is a jar: https://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/source/browse/trunk/warp-persist/#warp-persist%2Fdist

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend against using the published jar. Compared to the last commit, the published jars are outdated! There are fixes and improvements beyond last published jar. Imho it is good idea to build it yourself and look at some of the code. You only need to do _ant clean dist_ after the svn checkout.